# List of exe to open randomly

Tags: c++, windows

I would like to create a program where I have a list of game and open them randomly. I would like to know how to create a a list of exe file and how to choose a random element of a list

Comment: `#include <vector>` and `#include <random>` should get you started; but this isn't a code writing service, so you'll have to post what you've tried before most people will reply with something other than a down vote.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> progs{"game_one.exe", "game_two.exe"};
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,progs.size()-1);
    system(progs.at(distribution(generator)).c_str());
}
```